# Ubuntu 17.10 - Is It Possible To Add Application Or Application Shortcut To Desktop?

Tags: gnome, 17.10, 64-bit, shortcuts, .desktop

guys! I have a little question here.
I'm currently running Ubuntu 17.10 (no LTS).

I'm curious since Ubuntu 16, is it possible to add Application or Shortcut or anything beside folders on the desktop?

Really appreciate for any answers you all guys!
Thanks for reading.

Answer (score -1):

I read all solutions from [possible duplicate](https://askubuntu.com/questions/64222/how-can-i-create-launchers-on-my-desktop) - they demonstrate systematic illness of modern GNOME DE.

So the most user-friendly way is to install MATE DE (`ubuntu-mate-desktop` package) and create application launchers here on desktop:

- with simple drag-and-drop from *Applications* menu to desktop

or

- single right mouse click on desktop and selecting *Create Launcher* menu item from here:

  [image: create launcher on MATE DE desktop]